# How to run the map reduce jobs on EMRserverless?

Tags: amazon-emr, emr-serverless

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr-serverless/latest/APIReference/API_JobDriver.html), Amazon EMR serverless seems to accepts only Spark and Hive as job driver. Is there any support for [custom Hadoop jar](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_StepConfig.html) for map reduce jobs on serverless similar to EMR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. EMR serverless currently only supports Spark and Hive jobs, so no MapReduce.